# How to include PHP file in Wordpress that is outside the Wordpress Environment

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a custom CMS for a website that deals with 90% of the site's pages and content.

However, for the news/blog section of the site, I am using Wordpress.

I'm able to include the necessary Wordpress files to pull in posts to the main site, but cannot do the reverse.

I want to be able to call a php file into the header of Wordpress so I have access to the CMS's classes, primarily for navigation.

I've tried a search but can't seem to find an answer.

*Additional Information:*

- Wordpress is installed in `site.com/wordpress`
- The file I want to include is in `site.com/includes`

**Clarification:**

I don't want to create a custom template or include Wordpress functionality outside of Wordpress. I want to pull external classes from a CMS, which is a level above Wordpress, *into* Wordpress so that I can use it throughout the Wordpress installation.

Comment: What ever experience I have got, I can suggest, try to get what ever data you want to retrieve in functions.php, I guess It is possible .and after retrieving you can use that data with woocommerce functions and hooks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Can you share the code involved, and the error you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

You should go with custom page template.

Its an easy way to include php file in wordpress because in thisway you can easily include wordpress theme header and footer.

To create a custom page template.

You have to simply create new .php page and at start of page just include this code.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My custom page template name
*/
?>
// your code
```

To read in detail about Wordpress custom page template [click here](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-custom-page-templates-in-wordpress/)

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 :

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

Method 2 :

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-load.php');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks kaleem, but this isn't what I need -- I need to include a non-Wordpress file in Wordpress

Comment: Ohh-- then you can make custom template like this<?php  /* Template Name: abc */  ?>

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should that constant `WP_USE_THEMES` be neccessary to include any external file into Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by altering the `include` line to reference the folder above the Wordpress root.

So, the line became `require_once "../path/to/file"` instead of just `require_once "/path/to/file"`

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this?

```php
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/somefile.php');
//include_once
```

OR

```php
$rootpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$rootpath .= "/includes/somefile.php";
include_once($rootpath);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "perhaps"? Is there any reason to post an answer on a eight years old question? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: I've answered the user's 8 year old question, not just for the user, but for anyone else looking for a solution. If my solution is incorrect, speak and vote to that, not to the fact that i decided to add an updated answer. I said "perhaps this", as a kind way of saying, "try this".

Comment: Please add some explanation such that others can learn from your answer